# Find the mass of a plane

Tags: integration

$K$ is the plane between $y=\cos x, y = \sin 2x$ and the y-axis.

The density in $(x,y)$ is $\cos x$ mass units / area units.

Calculate the mass of $K$.

I've calculated the area of $K$, $$\int_0^{\pi/6} \cos x dx - \int_0^{\pi/6} \sin 2x dx = \frac{1}{4}$$

How do I proceed? I thought it would be as simple as $$ \int_0^{\pi/6} = \cos x dx$$.

The answer should be $$\frac{1}{12} \pi + \frac{3}{8} \sqrt{3} - \frac{2}{3}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{6}} cos(x)(cos(x)-sin(2x))dx $$

As for a fixed $x$ density is fixed so it is directly proportional length of the piece $cos(x)-sin (2x)$ and we we integrate alnong the $x$ acsess we are done.

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cdfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B6%7D%7D%20cos%28x%29%28cos%28x%29-sin%282x%29%29dx%20) is the calculation of result by Wolfram Alpha.